# 2 routers, a desktop and an Android

Tags: wifi

Router 1 is setup with WPA and a 32-character PSK. A Linux desktop is connected to it via Ethernet.

Router 2 has an 8-character PSK and is connected to Router 1 by Ethernet cable. 
Router 2 is used only by Android phones which connect to it by WiFi.

1. If an attacker compromises the weaker PSK on Router 2, is Router 1 at risk, or would the 32-character PSK stop them?
2. Do attackers have to crack the router's administrative User Name/Password before they can attempt to crack the PSK, or can they hack the router's PSK directly?
3. I asked the ISP manager why router 1 was set up as WPA, not WPA2 (he did the initial setup). He told me it was "difficult" to set up WPA2. Should I believe him? Why is it "difficult"?
4. How long does it take a skilled attacker to capture the entire network trace including the initial authentication handshake between the device and the router?

Comment: I think you mixed up your bits and bytes. Also, brute forcing the correct password might not be the only way to get access.

Comment: OK. 32 digit key. What other ways are there to gain access?

Comment: Is there WPS enabled? There are attacks against it. If the attacker takes control of the router 2, then it probably doesn't need to bother with WPA PSK, it's already basically joined the network (LAN and WLAN are usually bridged). Getting access to router 1 administration interface depends on its configuration - often that is accessible from connected clients (but they'd need the user/password). And all this is assuming things work as they should (No vulnerabilities like http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/527275 for example).

Comment: What does "via the Androids" mean?

Comment: @domen. Androids, I believe are 'smartphones' running on the Android OS created by the Goigle Empire

Comment: via the Androids means an attack from them as router 2's passphrase is weak. Router 1's key is good for my lifetime I understand.

Comment: This sounds like a setup for a new viral video.

Comment: ... walk into a bar

Comment: @Edwardo I think you're confusing how attacks on WiFi networks work. Unless the Androids themselves are compromised, an attacker wouldn't be going after the devices directly. They'd crack the network's PSK and join it with their own devices. The Androids' presence or non-presence on the network is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Unless they can access the management network of the router through router 2's connection, they can't normally get to your admin panel. make sure your administrative interfaces are on a different network than the network used for internet access.

Taking just into account how long it would take to bruteforce a 63 bit WPA-PSK key:

WPA-PSK passphrases get hashed 4096 times with a salt (which is the SSID of the AP). Now by 63 bits you probably mean a passphrase with 63 characters of length as  WPA-PSK has a 256-bit key (you can't change this). WPA supports ASCII so that's 128 possible characters. 63^128 = [this number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427esbuk5dh7tn). Now let's say you take [top notch GPU](http://golubev.com/gpuest.htm)s to bruteforce the key you could maybe get around 2.5 billion hashes every second. You would get the following calculation: ( Very Large Number/(2.5 billion / 4096 ) ) / 86400 = [another insanely large number](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ei358l3v2lq) **days** before you would be able to crack it (well half if you take probability into account). By then you'd probably be dead.

To your third remark, WPA2 is as difficult to setup as WPA. It's exactly the same principle (from a confguration point of view) just different algorithms. My guess is that his equipment does not support it.

**EDIT**

Miscalculation: it's 128^63 not the other way around. Regardless it's still a huge number.

Comment: I want to understand this correctly. Are you saying router 2 must have possession of router 1's key before it can communicate on the WPA2 network?

Comment: If you are connecting them wired then no. But then you also need to make sure your administrative interfaces are on a different network than the network used for internet access.

Comment: That's 128^63, not 63^128. Still quite large :-)

Comment: ah you are right

Comment: The two routers are on the same network and connected by ethernet wire. Router 1 is safe, I think, with its enormous passphrase. The question is can router 2 compromise router 1 in any way by an attack?

Answer (score 1):

If router 2 is wired to router 1, there is no need for a device on router 2 to have to break the PSK on router 1.  The pre-shared key is only used for wireless connections.  Once on the internal network, there is no key needed for access.  This is why you don't have to enter the key on your wired desktop, you just plug it in.  The key only applies to the radio link.

If they have access to router 2, they will not be able to administer router 1, but they will likely be able to see some of the traffic passing through the network on router 1.  They will also be able to connect with any computers on router 1.

If they already have access to the network, they have no need to attack the PSK, but yes, they could attack the PSK directly regardless of if anything else exists at all.  It could just be router 1 sitting in a room by itself and they could still attack the PSK directly.

For the third question, it isn't.  The only reason would be that some devices don't support WPA2, so they may do WPA for compatibility purposes by default.  I'd suggest switching it to WPA2.  If you don't have access to do that, I would request that the ISP disable the wireless and use WPA2 from my own router so that I could actually manage my security.  (I in fact do this at home where my cable modem supports Wi-fi, but the wi-fi is switched off.)

It varies based on key length and encryption used, but it takes anywhere from a few hours to weeks to break WEP or weak password derived WPA keys.  Last I knew, strong WPA keys were still pretty secure.  The information that is being transmitted can be recorded by an attacker in real time, they just have to obtain the encryption key before they can make sense of what is being sent.

Note that if you are accessing secure sites that use SSL, then even if the network link is compromised, you are still protected since SSL protects the information from your computer to the server and back.  Also note that your information on non-SSL connections can be read and even potentially modified on the Internet if someone is able to get between you and the destination server, so you should never rely on wireless encryption to keep your data safe.  It is mostly just a barrier to keeping unauthorized users from putting data on to your network.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If an attacker compromises the weaker PSK on Router 2, is Router 1 at risk, or would the 32-character PSK stop them?

This largely depends on how *exactly* your network is set up. Unfortunately, there's not enough detail in your post to give a proper analysis for your specific case. However, for variants of "Router 2 ... is connected to Router 1 by Ethernet cable" there's only two really relevant possibilities.

**Internet is connected to Router 2's WAN port. One of Router 2's LAN ports is connected to Router 1's WAN port.**

This is the ideal variant of your setup. Here, Router 1 will essentially treat any device connected to Router 2 as if it is just another device on the Internet. Therefore, all firewall and NAT rules will apply. In default configurations, this means that (absent a critical vulnerability in the router software) an attacker with access to Router 2's WiFi network *will not* gain access to Router 1's network without having to break the stronger WiFi PSK.

**Any other configuration.**

This includes all setups where Router 1 is the device connected directly to the Internet, as well as where Router 2 is connected to the Internet while the routers are connected to each other via LAN ports on each end. The critical piece to note here is that, in any configurations that would fall into this category, Router 1 will treat all devices connected to Router 2 as if they are part of the *local* network. At this point, any device connected to Router 2 - either by WiFi or Ethernet - almost may as well be connected directly to Router 1. No cracking of Router 1's PSK is required.

> `2.` Do attackers have to crack the router's administrative User Name/Password before they can attempt to crack the PSK, or can they hack the router's PSK directly?

The administrative username/password *only* protects the administration interface of the router. It does *not* prevent people from accessing the WiFi network. Otherwise, you would have to configure every client with both the admin username/password *and* the WiFi PSK.

> `3.` I asked the ISP manager why router 1 was set up as WPA, not WPA2 (he did the initial setup). He told me it was "difficult" to set up WPA2. Should I believe him? Why is it "difficult"?

These days, there's no reason it should be "difficult" at all. Most modern WiFi access points and clients support WPA2 right out of the box. Configuring WPA2 for PSK mode is no more or less difficult than configuring WPA for the same. The only time it becomes a problem is if there is older hardware (the access point, or client devices) involved which do not support WPA2. However, those are becoming fewer and farther between.

I'd suggest getting the admin password for the ISP's router and taking a look at it yourself. It's really none of their business how your WiFi is set up - apply any level of security you feel fit.

> `4.` How long does it take a skilled attacker to capture the entire network trace including the initial authentication handshake between the device and the router?

How long to *capture* the network trace? *Exactly* as long as it takes whatever network traffic they're capturing to occur. Now, how long does it take for them to be able to *read* that traffic as cleartext? That depends on how strong the encryption key and algorithm are (if any is used at all), and how much foreknowledge the attacker has. It also depends on what sort of hardware and software the attacker has at his disposal.

Comment: This answer deserves multiple up-votes. Many thanks to Iszi.